# can the apiserver connect to the Kubelet port of a node through CNI-provided network?

Tags: kubernetes, weave, cni

The [sleeve mode](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/concepts/router-encapsulation/) of Weave Net allows adding nodes behind NAT to the mesh, e.g. machines in a company network without external IP.

When Weave Net is used with Kubernetes, such nodes can be added to the cluster. The only drawback (besides the performance compared to [fastdp](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/tasks/manage/fastdp/)) seems to be that the Kubernetes API server can't reach the Kubelet port, so attaching to a Pod or getting logs doesn't work.

Is it somehow possible to work around this issue, e.g. by connecting to the Kubelet port of a NATed node through the weave network instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking under consideration how `kubectl exec` works and looking at Weave Net documentation makes it impossible to fix the cluster connectivity problem with Weave CNI.

Weave uses the underlying network for sending a packet to the node. I can't find any information saying that it is allowed to put the cluster node behind the NAT. More details can be found [here](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/concepts/fastdp-how-it-works/)

Therefore it is impossible to work around this issue as you suggested.

I hope it helps.